# SQL query to find the nearest element for list of numbers in an array

Tags: php, sql

I have an array with list of numbers, eg:[20,10,40,10,15], how to find the nearest element in this array with SQL query?

Comment: Show expected results and which dbms are you using?

Comment: update your code

Comment: Nearest to what?

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you have table `values` like:
id|value
and need to find value closest to 5

then

```
SELECT value from values where abs(value - 5) = (select min(abs(value -5)) from values)
```

Comment: This only works if the values table has no negative value